# Ошибка в source tree при клонировании репозитория

Tags: bitbucket, source-tree

При клонировании репозитория из bitbucket через source tree в новую папку, появляется ошибка когда указываю ссылку на исходный путь. В поле "Тип репозитория" уведомление "Это не правильный путь". Нажав "Детали" получаю и сам текст ошибки:

> fatal: bad config file line 1 in C:\Users\user_name/.gitconfig

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился. Отредактировал `.gitconfig` файл. Если кому понадобится:

```
[color]
    ui = true

[user]
 name = `user_name`

 email = `email`

[commit]

helper = cache --timeout=<3600>

[alias]

cd = checkout
dir = branch
mersq = merge --squash
free = branch -D
```